# Another Dictionary, Another Format Output

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, output

I'm dealing with Python nested dictionary. I have a dictionary;

```
contacts = {
            'name4': {'x': 5, 'y': 2, 'z': 7}, 
            'Name2': {'x': 5, 'y': 2, 'z': 5}, 
            'name3': {'x': 5, 'y': 2, 'z': 7}, 
            'Name1': {'x': 5, 'y': 2, 'z': 7}
           }
```

I need a loop that returns the dictionary that sorts the nest dictionary into 2 columns each. Obviously the exact spacing I'll have to play around with. Only the values returned on the nested dictionary as I have a header to show which each means.
Output I want is something like;

> Name4........5........2........7                          Name3........5........2........7
>   Name2........5........2........7                          Name1........5........2........7

Comment: Sorted by what? I think you mean you just want to display the data in multiple columns?

Comment: @justderb As long as the nested data stays together I don't care which person and their data goes where or in what column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this index checking technique in which you add either `'\t'` or `'\n'`

```
string = ''

for i in range(len(contacts.items())):
    string += contacts.items()[i][0] + ': '
    string += ' '.join([str(j) for j in contacts.items()[i][1].values()])

    if i % 2 == 0:
        string += '\t'

    if i % 2 != 0:
        string += '\n'

print string # prints in two columns
```

Comment: Is there anyways to truncate the name? I've been playing with the sizing of the name key and I wouldn't mind trucking it down to a limit of like 15 characters.